# Applying dataframe-returning function to every row of base dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, apply, pandas-groupby

**Toy example**

Suppose that `base_df` is the tiny dataframe shown below:

```
In [221]: base_df
Out[221]: 
     seed
I S      
0 a     0
  b     1
1 a     2
  b     3
```

Note that `base_df` has a 2-level multi-index for the rows.  (Part of the problem here involves "propagating" this multi-index's values in a derived dataframe.)

Now, the function `fn` (definition given at the end of this post) takes an integer `seed` as argument and returns a 1-column dataframe indexed by string keys<sup>1</sup>.  For example:

```
In [222]: fn(0)
Out[222]: 
              F
key            
01011  0.592845
10100  0.844266

In [223]: fn(1)
Out[223]: 
              F
key            
11110  0.997185
01000  0.932557
11100  0.128124
```

I want to generate a new dataframe, in essence, by applying `fn` to every row of `base_df`, and concatenating the resulting dataframes vertically.  More specifically, the desired result would look like this:

```
                  F
I S key            
0 a 01011  0.592845
    10100  0.844266
  b 11110  0.997185
    01000  0.932557
    11100  0.128124
1 a 01101  0.185082
    01110  0.931541
  b 00100  0.070725
    11011  0.839949
    11111  0.121329
    11000  0.569311
```

IOW, conceptually, the desired dataframe is obtained by generating one "sub-dataframe" for each row of `base_df`, and concatenating these sub-dataframes vertically.  The sub-dataframe corresponding to each row has a 3-level multi-index.  The first two levels (`I` and `S`) of this multi-index come from `base_df`'s multi-index value for that row, while its last level (`key`), as well as the values for the (lone) `F` column come from the dataframe returned by `fn` for that row's `seed` value.

The part I'm not clear on is how to propagate the row's original multi-index value to the rows of the dataframe created by `fn` for that row's `seed` value.

**IMPORTANT:** I'm looking for a way to do this that is agnostic to the names of the `base_df`'s multi-index's levels, and their number.

---

I tried the following

```
base_df.apply(lambda row: fn(row.seed), axis=1)
```

...but the evaluation fails with the error

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 2), indices imply (4, 1)
```

Is there some convenient way to do what I'm trying to do?

---

Here's the definition of `fn`.  Its internals are unimportant as far as this question is concerned.  What matters is that it takes an integer `seed` as argument, and returns a dataframe, as described earlier.

```
import numpy
def fn(seed, _spec='{{0:0{0:d}b}}'.format(5)):
    numpy.random.seed(int(seed))
    n = numpy.random.randint(2, 5)
    r = numpy.random.rand(n)
    k = map(_spec.format, numpy.random.randint(0, 31, size=n))
    result = pandas.DataFrame(r, columns=['F'], index=k)
    result.index.name = 'key'
    return result
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> In this example, these keys happen to correspond to the binary representation of some integer between 0 and 31, inclusive, but this fact plays no role in the question.</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**
*`groupby`*

```
base_df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).apply(fn)

                  F
I S key            
0 a 11010  0.385245
    00010  0.890244
    00101  0.040484
  b 01001  0.569204
    11011  0.802265
    00100  0.063107
1 a 00100  0.947827
    00100  0.056551
    11000  0.084872
  b 11110  0.592641
    00110  0.130423
    11101  0.915945
```

---

**Option 2**
*`pd.concat`*

```
pd.concat({t.Index: fn(t.seed) for t in base_df.itertuples()})

                  F
    key            
0 a 11011  0.592845
    00011  0.844266
  b 00101  0.997185
    01111  0.932557
    00000  0.128124
1 a 01011  0.185082
    10010  0.931541
  b 10011  0.070725
    01010  0.839949
    01011  0.121329
    11001  0.569311
```